Finding $c$ such that $\frac{c^2x}{2cx+6x+9} = x$ for all real $x\neq -3/2$
I ran into the following confusion while doing recreational algebra (I'm very much a non-expert). I'm hoping someone can enlighten me as to whatever silly mistake I'm making!

Problem:
$$\frac{c^2x}{2cx+6x+9} = x$$ for all real $x \neq -3/2$. What is $c$?

The solution is $-3$, and I understand how to arrive at that solution. What I don't understand is the following:
We have $$c^2x = x(2cx+6x+9) \tag1$$
Now, let's assume that $x \neq 0$. We'll deal with the $0$-case later. Then I can do the following:
$$c^2 = 2cx+6x+9 \tag2$$
Rearranging, I get
$$x = \frac{c^2-9}{2c+6} \tag3$$
I simply don't understand this result. I can't see that I've made a mistake up to this point. But it looks like all real $x \neq 0,-3/2$ suddenly equal one and the same unknown constant. And when I insert what's supposed to be the solution to this problem, I get $\frac{0}{0}$. What does this mean?
How do I "interpret" what's happening there?
Thanks for humoring my question. (:

when $c=-3$, dividing by $2c+6$ is dividing by $0$

The mistake you have made is that when $c = -3$, you cannot divide by $2c + 6$, since that would be dividing by zero.
In fact, that is how you can solve the problem. If $c$ is equal to any number other than $-3$, then you would have exactly one solution for $x$, namely the one you found, $\frac{c^2 - 9}{2c+6}$. However, when $c = -3$, the coefficient of $x$ is $0$, so you can't divide. Instead, you get the equation $9 = 9$. This is true for all $x$, so we have proved that the original equation holds when $c = -3$.

Thanks for being nice! (: So, before knowing the answer, I of course didn't know that dividing by 2c+6 is dividing by 0. Do I understand correctly: Running into $x = \frac{c^2-9}{2c+6}$, given that this is supposed to be true for all reals, is like running into a contradiction. Some assumption must be faulty, and here it's the (implicit) assumption that division by 2c+6 is possible.

@ichbinviele Yes! This is an idea sometimes used. However, make sure to check that the $c = -3$ actually is a solution.

Did you mean $2c+6$ where you typed $2x+6$ (in two places)?

@J.W.Tanner Thanks for the catch!


whatever silly mistake I'm making

You're dividing by $0$ when "rearranging."
When $c=-3$, $$2c+6=0.$$
